# Seems illogical probability question

Tags: probability

Two basketball players each throw one shot to the basket. One of the players probability that he will score is 0.7. And both players getting ball in the basket probability is 0.82.

P(A) = 0.7
P(AB) = 0.82

And need to find out P(B). Others guys probability.

But what I cant seem to understand is that both players scoring probability is higher than A guys probability.

What I tried to do was:

P(AB) = P(A) * P(B)

0.82 = 0.7 * P(B)

P(B) = 0.82/0.7 => larger than 1 so is impossible.

Explain how that is possible and how can I calculate it?

Answer is 0.4

Comment: Are you sure that $P(AB)$ is $0.82$ and not $0.28$? The reversal of the digits is consistent with the answer $0.4$ given to you. In any case, $AB$ is a _subset_ of $A$ and cannot have larger probability.

Comment: Agree, its said it is 0.82.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer, the question should say that the probability of *at least one* player getting the ball in the basket is 0.82.

Edit: skv has suggested that I write out the calculation:

$$\mathbb{P}(A)=0.7$$
$$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)=0.82$$
$$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)=1-(1-\mathbb{P}(A))(1-\mathbb{P}(B))$$
$$0.82=1-0.3(1-\mathbb{P}(B))$$
$$0.3(1-\mathbb{P}(B))=0.18$$
$$1-\mathbb{P}(B)=0.6$$
$$\mathbb{P}(B)=0.4$$

Dilip's digit reversal suggestion would also give an answer of 0.4.

Comment: I think adding the calculation for this would serve everyone better

Comment: translate google transleted "What is the accuracy of the other basketball player?"